# Width of img parent is not scaled when image is up-scaled

Tags: html, css

Container:
[image]

Image parent:
[image]

Image:
[image]

**Example**: https://codesandbox.io/s/q4q6lwj719

The image on the right (and a couple of css rules) makes left image render larger than its natural size. But its parent doesn't scale with it and is sized as if the image was rendered in its natural size.

Seems weird to me. Am I missing something?

**NOTE**: Some times (seems to be random) it's fixed in Chrome (v72.0.3626.119). In Firefox (v65), it's always broken.

Comment: Sorry I am not able understand what exactly you want. If you can explain how you would like them to show up then i can help

Comment: I want `div.item` to stretch horizontally based on its content width (the image). AFAIK, This is what normally happens for an element with `display: inline-block`

Comment: But it's sized based on **natural width of image**. In other words, the problem is only for the case when image is rendered larger than its natural size. Which is the case in this example.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the first element style `<div style="display: flex">`. By default the style `align-items` sets to `stretch` so your image makes larger than its natural size. Use the style `align-items: center;` or set it to `baseline` or whatever you want to prevent changing the size.

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.item {
  display: inline-block;
  max-height: 250px;
}

.item img {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div style="display: flex; align-items: center;">
      <div class="item video">
        <img
          alt="Quiz of Kings (بازی آنلاین)video"
          src="https://www.conti-engineering.com/CMSPages/GetFile.aspx?guid=6f8b829a-e0a5-49e1-9882-122d1d3efb06"
        />
      </div>
      <img
        class="item"
        src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSgKNQKR-foUvskwO90hnlG_pyTQfeMsyIaFfJiWQV_AkTc8TPB"
      />
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I actually want the `div.item` to stretch. I want images to have equal height. width should be adjusted according to aspect ratio.

Comment: The most weird thing is that when I uncheck 'display: inline-block' in chrome dev tools and check it again, `div.item` resizes correctly to match image width!